# Calling cron twice or triple sometimes

Tags: php, cron

I had to done something like "cron Job" because I don't have access to cPanel

My logic of this cron Job class, was when someone hits something from the website, verify the time and call the class.

...so....

Here is my class of cronJob, and **my problem is that sometimes it calls the class twice or triple**.. (*maybe the current time from two or more users is the same...*)

```
<?php
class cronJob extends Core {
    public function execute() {
        include("interfaces/cronJob.php");
        $items = $this->query("SELECT `id`, `class`, `interval`, `time` FROM `cron_job`");
        while($item = $this->fetch($items))
        {
            if($this->getTime() > $item['time']) {
                $this->query("UPDATE `cron_job` SET `time` = '".($this->getTime() + $item['interval'])."' WHERE `id` = '".$item['id']."'");
                $this->getLog("cronJob: ".$this->getTime()." Class: ".$item['class']);

                include_once("cron/".$item['class'].".php");
                $job = new $item['class'];
                $job->run();
            } 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

...and... here is the time function (I do not think it's necessary :P)

```
public function getTime() {
    return time() + 305;
}
```

The logs:

```
2013-04-14 12:59:02 - cronJob: 1365890342 Class: updateFiles
2013-04-14 12:59:37 - cronJob: 1365890377 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:00:13 - cronJob: 1365890413 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:00:49 - cronJob: 1365890449 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:01:25 - cronJob: 1365890485 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:02:01 - cronJob: 1365890521 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:02:37 - cronJob: 1365890557 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:03:13 - cronJob: 1365890593 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:03:49 - cronJob: 1365890629 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 01:04:25 - cronJob: 1365890665 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 **01:05:01** - cronJob: 1365890701 Class: updateTrivia
2013-04-14 **01:05:01** - cronJob: 1365890701 Class: updateTrivia
```

Table:

[image]

so... does anyone have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Why are you fetching ALL of the cron jobs? You could limit to only fetch the jobs that should be run, e.g. `SELECT ... WHERE time > $this->getTime()`.

Comment: @MarcB I have to fetch all of them and than to verify "if($this->getTime() > $item['time'])"

Comment: so? why can't the database do that? $item['time'] comes from the db, so just send $this->getTime() over in your select query, and save yourself having to throw away all the jobs that DON'T need execution. e.g. you're driving to the store, buying EVERYTHING, then throwing away everything escept the candy bar you wanted.

Comment: @MarcB yeah, but there is an update in while... which means there's an infinite loop... everytime "time" is bigger than "$this->getTime();"

Comment: no. because the select that gets the jobs will be done by the time you start updating rows. remember. it won't rerun the whole query every time you fetch a row.

Comment: already tried, wanna see the logs ? http://pastebin.com/cFnvkEBg

Comment: do you hav emultiple copies of this cron processor running at the same time? If so, two parallel scripts **WILL* generally get the SAME set of jobs do to, because neither script is locking/marking which jobs it's handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to:

- Block it using database: For example, lock tables / start transaction (Careful, option not avaiable on MyISAM engine).
- Write and read from a file. If file's contents != "x", you skip the update.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a feature commonly referred to as an [**exclusive lock**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29).

[Another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325806/best-way-to-obtain-a-lock-in-php) might give you some inspiration on how to implement a lock in your case.
Note, that the mentioned `APC` feature is an optional PHP module not shipped with most standard distributions (and not present on many web hosts)